# Find span inside two parents

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I would like to get some text inside an element which is nested in other elements:

```
<tr class="odd">
    <td>

<span class="b"> one </span>

<span class="b"> two </span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get the text "one" so using my logic:

```
var t = $('.odd td span:nth-of-type(1)').text();

alert(t);
```

I get blank. What am I doing wrong?

[Example at JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Tmr/14/)

Comment: TR must be child of TABLE element

Comment: I like `span:nth-child(1)` better.

Comment: @mts7 This is just a basic example for big script, nth-child will not do

Comment: @A. Wolff I thought browsers these days don't give a damn about proper formatting and just fix everything like google search:) I was wrong

Comment: Browsers don't fix *everything*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Tmr/17/)***

The issue is that the html is not well formed. If you had wrapped your tr element in a table, it would have alerted the proper value.

```
<table>
<tr class="odd">
<td>

<span class="b"> one </span>

<span class="b"> two </span>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ah I see:) I copied the table from some place and edited a lot, should have sticked to the original. Thank you.